# Equation Formula Review/Proof

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I hope everyone's healthy and happy and enjoying the sun. (*if in the Southern Hemisphere)*

Would somebody mind having a quick check over so the below to know if I'm applying the correct methodology for required application

The Question;
I've decried to put all our garden sprinkler settings into excel to help calculate usage, costs while trying to optimise watering settings.
The general formula I am using is; *(I've included a image for an example)*

- Cost=(R/1000)*L
- L=(Flow*T)*Nodes​
- T=Min*D​
- D=ROUNDDOWN((End-Start+1)/Interval,0)​

Where;

- R = Cost Per 1KL
- L = Total Litres Used
- T = Total Run Time Cost per
- 1 Kilolitres= 2.99
- Flow = 1.6 (Flow Rate Per/Min of 1x 90° Sprinkler Head)
- Nodes = Amount of Sprinkler Heads
- Min = Watering Run Time in Minutes
- Start = Watering Start Date
- End = Watering End Date
- Interval = Watering Interval Day

Thats the method of calculating the costs. I'd love to hear anyone's thoughts and please do let me know if I've missed anything.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated and many thanks in advance. :)
*P.S; if anyone knows how to calculate the usage and costs for running drip line irrigation, I'd love to hear it. :) (The Drip line is about 153 meters in length with hole spacing every 300mm apart. It's 2.2 l/hr Flow. I haven't been able to think of how to calculate this)*

For costing example; (sorry for the image, I didn't know if I could upload a sheet)
[image]

OP
https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/equation-formula-review-proof-for-garden-watering.1193183/

Comment: 2.2 l/hr * number of hours * price per litre…

Comment: ok, so I pretty much got all the other calculations correct. Cheers : )